# Не работает DeserializeObject C# JSON

Tags: c#, json

Не понимаю в какой тип данных нужно десериализировать json, чтобы можно было достать его значения. Пробовал словарь или список, но всегда выдаёт одну и ту же ошибку. Сам JSON файл:

```
[{
  "quoteText": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Yogi Berra"
},
{
  "quoteText": "A house divided against itself cannot stand.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Abraham Lincoln"
},
```

Ошибка:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 3."

  Questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(Data);
```

Comment: ваш json - массив словарей, а не словарь. Нужно JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>

Comment: @vitidev 'Dictionary<string, string>" является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте.Ошибка (

Comment: Создайте класс, у которого будут 2 свойства `quoteText` и `quoteAuthor` с типом `string` и десериализуйте в `List<ВашКласс>`, использовать тут словари - бред.

Comment: Мой код работает. У вас список словарей. И он парсится моим вариантом. Ну а то, что у вас не хватает закрывающей ] списываю на проблемы копипаста при создании вопроса.